# Android (Intent.ACTION_VIEW) not recognizing on Mi device for mimeType video/mp4

Tags: android, mime-types

I have taken a video from camera which gets saved in camera/DCIM location on sdCard

Now my app takes the local path of the video and try playing the video using default video player with below code

```
 private void playVideo(String path) {
        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(path);
        Intent videoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        videoIntent.setDataAndType(videoUri, "video/*");
        if (videoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(videoIntent, null));
        }
    }
```

Now issue is the video doesn't play with a toast "Media view not found" on Mi devices + a few other.

But the same video plays through through selecting video from FileManager applications.

So I guess the issue is not with VideoPlayer. INSTEAD I think it's the issue with what mimeType is getting shared to the player. But thats just my assumption.

Anyone faced a similar issue, I need help as this issue is eating up my time.
Thanks

Comment: "I have taken a video from camera which gets saved in camera/DCIM location on sdCard" -- therefore, you know what the actual MIME type is. Hence, you should replace `video/*` with the actual MIME type.

Comment: tried that as well, video/mp4 for my mp4 video... doesn't help

Comment: What exactly is `path`? IOW, if you log it to LogCat, what does it look like?

Comment: path -  "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20160113_130138.mp4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20160113_130138.mp4` is not a valid string representation of a `Uri`. A `Uri` needs a scheme.

Presumably, once upon a time, you had a `File` object for this. Use that, and `Uri.fromFile()`, instead of `Uri.parse()`. Or, use `Uri.fromFile(new File(path))`. This will give you the proper scheme setup.

Comment: Thanks a lot, was breaking my head on this for past 8 hours ... setting schema works... instead of this - Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(path) ...I put  Uri videoUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));

Comment: So one more question - how did the 'path' worked for few other devices like Nexus 5, even though I was using Uri without a schema ?